# 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConncetion'

Tags: python, authorize.net

Hi I have the following code but am getting an error that the `module object has no attribute HTTPSConnection`:

```
from ecomstore import settings
import httplib
import urllib

def do_auth_capture(amount='0.00', card_num=None, exp_date=None, card_cvv=None):
    delimiter = '|'
    raw_params = {
        'x_login':settings.AUTHNET_LOGIN,
        'x_tran_key':settings.AUTHNET_KEY,
        'x_type':'AUTH_CAPTURE',
        'x_amount':amount,
        'x_version':'3.1',
        'x_card_num':card_num,
        'x_exp_date':exp_date,
        'x_delim_char':delimiter,
        'x_relay_response':'FALSE',
        'x_delim_data':'TRUE',
        'x_card_code':card_cvv
        }

    params = urllib.urlencode(raw_params)
    headers = {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
               'content-length':len(params)}

    post_url = settings.AUTHNET_POST_URL
    post_path = settings.AUTHNET_POST_PATH
    cn = httplib.HTTPSConncetion(post_url,httplib.HTTPS_PORT)
    cn.request('POST',post_path, params, headers)
    return cn.getresponse().read().split(delimiter)
```

Is there a reason this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    cn = httplib.HTTPSConncetion(post_url,httplib.HTTPS_PORT)
```

You've misspelled "Connection".

Comment: @cfarm54: Took me two looks to see it. ;-)